# How to get uri to included asset in Uno Platform?

Tags: uno-platform

For integrating with a android binding project I need to provide a Uri pointing to a .zip file, which I have included in the assets and designated as AndroidAsset. How do I get the Uri for such a file?
I already tried `ms-appx:///Assets/file.zip` and `file:///Assets/file.zip`

Update:
Import to note is, that the function consuming the Uri is Android native code, so I suspect that ms-appx:// doesn't get resolved properly.

Update2:
It is not possible to provide a stream.
The method I am calling is shown in the sample here: https://github.com/Laerdal/Xamarin.Nordic.DFU.Android/blob/7244627c09e97e05ee2c8e05744f19055981486b/Sample/Nordic/FirmwareUpdater.cs#L27.

```
_dfuServiceInitiator.SetZip(firmwareZipFile);
```

The native implementation is shown here: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library/blob/07bdaa50cfc5786790bf1ac589b14931de65d099/dfu/src/main/java/no/nordicsemi/android/dfu/DfuServiceInitiator.java#L620

```
public DfuServiceInitiator setZip(@NonNull final Uri uri) {
    return init(uri, null, 0, DfuBaseService.TYPE_AUTO, DfuBaseService.MIME_TYPE_ZIP);
}
```

Comment: What's the native code looking like ? Can you provide a stream instead of an uri ?

Comment: @JérômeLaban I updated the question with the answer to your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files read from the `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()` method may not return a stable path on UWP, and this is particularly the case on particularly on Android or WebAssembly, where the file is not necessarily on the file system.

On Android, the file is a `Stream` directly built from the APK file, and on WebAssembly it is stored in a temporary location.

In order to use keep a stable copy of the file, use the following:

```cs
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new System.Uri("ms-appx:///TextFile.txt"));
var newFile = await file.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

var txt = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(newFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` can be used to get a `StorageFile` object from an ms-appx Uri.

Then you can use the `Path` property of the `StoragFile` to get the local android path. Make note to set the build action of the file as `Content`.

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new System.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/file.zip"));
Android.Net.Uri zipUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///"+file.Path);
```

Comment: Note that this may not work properly as the returned file path is only an artifact of the current implementation (the file is stored on the disk temporarily). It would be best if you were to create a copy the file to a location that your application manages entirely. In Android, resources are provided as streams, not files, and Uno will eventually behave this way as well, making the `Name` property of the file irrelevant.

Comment: @JérômeLaban I am going to assume you mean the `Path` property? Your suggestion comes down to getting the Stream of the file like usually and saving that to a temporary file that we do know the absolute location of? Feel free to submit that answer too, since in the context of Uno it might be more suitable.

Comment: Right, sorry, `Path` property :) I'll provide an additional answer then.